# How do I improve LibGDX 3D rendering performance?

Tags: java, performance, opengl, libgdx, rendering

I'm working on rendering a tiled sphere with LibGDX, aimed at producing a game for desktop. Here are some images of what I've got so far: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZJZA.jpg. I'm rendering 10,000 or so ModelInstances, all of which are generated from code using their own ModelBuilders. They each contain 3 or 4 trianglular parts, and every ModelInstance corresponds to its own Model. Here's the exact rendering code I'm using to do so:

```
    modelBatch.begin(cam);
    // Render all visible tiles
    visibleCount = 0;
    for (Tile t : tiles) {
        if (isVisible(cam, t)) {
            // t.rendered is a ModelInstance produced earlier by code.
            // the Model corresponding to the instance is unique to this tile.
            modelBatch.render(t.rendered, environment);
            visibleCount++;
        }
    }
    modelBatch.end();
```

The ModelInstances are not produced from code each frame, just drawn. I only update them when I need to. The "isVisible" check is just some very simple frustum culling, which I followed from this tutorial https://xoppa.github.io/blog/3d-frustum-culling-with-libgdx/. As you can tell from my diagnostic information, my FPS is terrible. I'm aiming for at least 60 FPS rendering what I hope is a fairly-simple scene of tons of polygons. I just know I'm doing this in a very inefficient way.

I've done some research on how people might typically solve this issue, but am stuck trying to apply the solutions to my project. For example, dividing the scene into chunks is recommended, but I don't know how I could make use of that when the player is able to rotate the sphere and view all sides. I read about occlusion culling, so that I might only render ModelInstances on the side of the sphere facing the camera, but am at a loss as to how to implement that in LibGDX.

Additionally, how bad is it that every ModelInstance uses its own Model? Would speed be improved if only one shared Model object was used? If anyone could point me to more resources or give me any good recommendations on how I can improve the performance here, I'd be thankful.

Comment: I'm not totally familiar with Libgdx's 3d, but I think 10000 model instances means there are 10000 draw calls. Which is not as bad as 10000 sprite batch flushes since the model data doesn't change, but still bad. I think you will see a big improvement if you can merge some of those model instances so you have fewer of them. Also, on a mid range or low end phone, 30000+ vertices is probably too much for smooth performance.

Comment: You might be able to use to camera's far plane to frustum cull almost half of the vertices by setting the far plane to be slightly farther away from the camera than the center of the sphere. But I think your first bottleneck is likely the high number of model instances.

Answer (score 0):

If the tiles are eventually intended to be solid, one improvement you can make is to turn on [back-face culling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-face_culling). This will cause any faces not facing the camera to not be rendered (i.e. one side of each face becomes invisible). For a sphere that means the GPU would only need to render about half the faces.

Combining the object into a single Model may also have a large impact. It may be the difference between 10,000 draw calls and 1 (it depends on how smart that modelBatch object is, as it might do the combining behind the scenes). If the user will sometimes be zoomed pretty close a chunking approach might help so that you can continue doing frustum culling.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've been doing some of these similar techniques from advice I got in other threads and it improved my performance about 60-fold. Once I get some of my code in order I'm going to post a write-up here.

Comment: Did you end up making the write-up you mentioned here?